# Use query of multiple fields in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection that includes names of books.

I have an activity with search field where I let the user to find a book by querying the collection.

The following query works good for me:

```
db.collection( "Books" )
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo( "BookTitle", s.toString() ).whereLessThanOrEqualTo( "BookTitle", s.toString() + "\uF7FF" ).limit( 5 ).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                DOING SOMETHING
                }
            }
        } );
```

However, I am adding now another field to some of the document in my collection called `UserID` and to query all the Books that doesnt have this field like this:

```
db.collection( "Books" )
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo( "BookTitle", s.toString() ).whereLessThanOrEqualTo( "BookTitle", s.toString() + "\uF7FF" ).whereNotEqualTo( "UserID", null ).limit( 5 ).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    DO SOMETHING
                }
            }
        } );
```

I got an error saying:

```
All where filters with an inequality (notEqualTo, notIn, lessThan, lessThanOrEqualTo, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqualTo) must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'BookTitle' and 'UserID'
```

Is there some other way I can achieve this result?

I guess I can get documents and later to check what is the value of UserID in them but I might read unneeded documents this way.

Thank you

Comment: For your reference, see sample of [valid and invalid range filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) on Firebase docs.

Comment: @Dondi The OP is already aware of the limitations and is looking for a workaround.

Comment: What is the meaning of the presence of "UserID" in each Book document? Does a book belong to a single user? Why would you store null?

Comment: @AlexMamo,I want to have inside "Books" collection two types of documents. One is books that belong to users and therefore they will appear in searches and other type with UserID null which is used for other part of the algorithm and wont show in the searches since no user has this book.

Comment: Then why not using two separate collections for that?